# WPF Nullable<T> and class binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpf-4.0

I have a **int?** and **string** properties in my model and this cannot be changed (I cannot split this properties into pairs of two separate properties, for instance).

I want to bind these properties to Checkbox and TextBox. So if CheckBox is not checked value should be **null**, and if CheckBox is checked value should be whatever entered into the TextBox.

What is the right way to implement this with WPF? I use .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: When you say "value", you mean the value of the "int?" field?  Or the value of the string field?  Clarify the relationship between the two fields.  Or do you mean each field in your model needs its own checkbox and textbox pair?

Comment: No relationship, just want solution for both Nullable<struct> and class. I mean string has no HasValue property to bind to, like int? does, so I need solution for both cases.

Comment: So basically, the int? should be 1/null depending on checkbox IsChecked and the string should be the value of the textbox, but only if the checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I read this question completely wrongly at first.

Assuming you have a Model like this

```
class FakeModel
{
    public int? IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then the best way to solve this is to implement a ViewModel such as

```
    class FakeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private  FakeModel _fakeModel;

    public FakeViewModel(FakeModel  model)
    {
        _fakeModel = model;
    }
    public bool IntChecked
    {
        get { return _fakeModel.IntegerValue.HasValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                IntegerValue = -1; //for example
            else
                IntegerValue = null; //to reset
            OnPropertyChanged("IntChecked");
        }
    }

    public int IntegerValue
    {
        get { return _fakeModel.IntegerValue.Value; }
        set { _fakeModel.IntegerValue.Value = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IntegerValue");
        }
    }

    public bool StringChecked
    {
        get { return _fakeModel.StringValue.HasValue; }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                StringValue = -1; //for example
            else
                StringValue = null; //to reset
            OnPropertyChanged("StringChecked");
        }
    }

    public int StringValue
    {
        get { return _fakeModel.StringValue.Value; }
        set
        {
            _fakeModel.StringValue.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StringValue");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string callerName)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(callerName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This includes a basic implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, which you could alternatiely inherit from a base class or mvvm library such as Caliburn.Micro MMVMLite or ReactiveUI.

For more info on view models or MVVM, check out [Josh Smith on MVVM from MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you may want to wrap a ViewModel around your Model class instead of binding it directly to the view.

In this case, you would have something like a "MyDataViewModel" and it would expose a string property and a bool property.  When these properties are changed by the bindings, it would update the underlying model class with the appropriate values for each field.

Binding directly to your model class is usually only done when your model class supports rich binding features, such as Data Annotations, and when you use a data service class to handle saving and loading these objects.